# Python object class mutable default value

Tags: python

Let's say we have a simple python model class.

```
 class Library:

     def __init__():
         self.library_name = None
         self.books = []
```

We would use that by:

```
new_library = Library()
new_library.library_name = "Delhi International Library"
```

This would be an empty library with no books. Is this safe? I know you shouldn't use mutable types in the method signature due to when it is evaluated.

Comment: `new_library.library_name = "Delhi International Library"` would be fine, I'm guessing `.name` is a typo?

Comment: thanks, I updated the typo.

Comment: The problem is when you use a mutable value as the *default* value for a parameter, not when you pass a mutable value as an argument.

Comment: Perfect, I thought it was OK. So setting ```self.books = []``` as part of the __init__ but not as an argument is OK.

Comment: Correct. Every instance of `Library` will then have its *own* (initially empty) list of books, rather than sharing a reference to a single central book list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way to use a mutable type for a default value is to use a `None` default value:

```
class Library:
     def __init__(self, name, books=None):
         self.library_name = name
         self.books = [] if books is None else books


new_library = Library("Delhi International Library")
```

Here `name` is a required param because IMHO a library should have a name, but you could also use a default if you later will have to create a library with no parameters.

And `books` is optional. If it is not given, you will get en empty library, and if you pass it on first time, it will not become the default because `None` is not mutable...

Comment: How about init(self, name, books=[ ]) and self.books=books ?

Comment: @Mercury No. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument.

Comment: are there any performance benefits to doing it that way then not having it in the initilizer and instead doing it the way I did in. In reality there are 20 or so variables and I find it get's messy?

Comment: There are neither benefit nor drawback on a performance point of view. What matters is what is more readable or easy to use, and it really depends on the use case. Sometimes you will declare default values, sometimes you will declare no parameters...

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, library_name, books=None):
        self.library_name = library_name
        self.books = books or []
```

and then instantiate like:

```
new_library = Library("Delhi International Library")
```

Comment: Using a list as a default value for an argument isn't a good idea, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Thanks - are there any performance benefits to doing it that way then not having it in the initilizer and instead doing it the way I did in. In reality there are 20 or so variables and I find it get's messy.

Comment: It's rarely necessary to make a copy of whatever list you do pass; it's often a temporary object that would be garbage-collected if `self.book` didn't save a referent to it. Use `books=None`, then set `self.books = [] if books is None else book` (or an equivalent)

Comment: That is, if someone creates a `Library` and doesn't want that object to make changes to its existing list, the *caller* passes a copy as an argument, rather than assuming `Library` will make its own copy.